# Condition for ajax to satisfy both create and update action - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a function to auto save text input like this:

```
saveToDB = function() {
      var form, id;
      form = $('#create_article');
      id = (form.attr('action')).split("/").pop(-1);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/articles/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          $('.form-status-holder').html('Saving...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var jqObj;
          jqObj = jQuery(data);
          $('.form-status-holder').delay(5000).hide();
        }
      });
    };
    $('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
      var timeoutId;
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      return timeoutId = setTimeout((function() {
        saveToDB();
      }), 5000);
```

The problem is that, this code only work with `update` action and I want to do the same with `create` action too. Two actions use the same `create_article` form. The button `create` and `edit`(update) is in index file before moving to the form. How do I notice what button was clicked and then do the `saveToDB` function then use the correct url(`/admin/articles/' + id` for update and `/admin/articles/` for create)?

Comment: You can check the value of id. By putting in url `'/admin/articles/' + (id || '')`

Comment: @janmvtrinidad, in the case `id = null`, this link didn't work(`'/admin/articles/' +  ''`)

Comment: '/admin/articles/' = '/admin/articles/' + '', in that value it should work as a valid string and url.

Comment: Yes, when I keep two link separately, but if I put this link: `'/admin/articles/' + (id || '')` It works only when I update(edit)

Comment: By the way, why you need to know which button is click? Is identifying id is not enough for that?

Comment: because the function above is in a form, create and update button will link to this form, but the action for create and edit(update) are not the same, then it's the reason I want to check which button is clicked. The id here is the id of the record(integer) when editing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112018/discussion-between-dinhngochien-and-janmvtrinidad).